# Wrong values from EXTRACT time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm using pgAdminIII with postgresql 9.5.1.
I'm trying to extract 'hours' from a time column using:
`SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time::time))
FROM myable;`

The time in the table is `19:56:00`, but the above query returns `15`.

Also, EXTRACT minutes is wrong:
`SELECT (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time::time))
FROM mytable;`
returns `8`.
Seconds are wrong as well.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: please check the values you are using, extraction works just fine `SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '19:56:00'::time);` will give you `19`

Comment: From everything I can see in pgAdmin and Excel the values show 19:56:00 but the wrong values are still returned.  Double and triple checked.

Comment: make sure table has no timezone offset. it would be great to see output table definition output `\d yourtableName` from `psql`

Comment: Could you `select extract(hour from time::time), extract(minute from time::time), time::time, time from mytable;` in `psql` and include the result in your question? What type is this `time` column?